# Using geth Light Node to detect ERC-721 transactions

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, erc-721

Is it possible to use a geth light node to detect incoming transactions executed via ERC-721 contracts?

I have experienced being not able to get receipts using getTransactionReceipt in native and ERC-20 transactions if I'm using a light node. I'm assuming it would be the same for ERC-721?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can detect, yes same for ERC-20/ERC-721. Listen for the `Transfer` event.

If you would like a more specific answer, please post code that you have attempted to use to solve this problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! You meant "Yes" for the first question or the second one? I'll check the Transfer event.

Comment: All yes. Updated.